# Getting buttons position in fragment with viewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, ontouchlistener

I'm building an app with 2 fragments (with ViewPager). Each fragment consists of 4 buttons. I use also onTouch listener with these buttons. I use getLocationOnScreen(...) method to get the view's (button) position on screen. But as I slide from first fragment to the second one, the location of the next 4 buttons is relative to the first fragment. I mean, the x coordinate of these buttons is taking into consideration the previous fragment width.
My question is - how do I get the second fragment's buttons position relative to this fragment page and not the previous one?

Thanks!

**EDIT :**  Added a code snippet:

Here is how i keep my buttons position on screen into a hash-map collection (this is done for each of the two fragments i have):

```
public void getViewsPosition(final ArrayList<View> viewArr) {
    for (final View v : viewArr) {
        final ViewTreeObserver vto = v.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                int[] i = new int[2];
                v.getLocationOnScreen(i);
                _rect = new Rect(i[0], i[1], i[0] + v.getWidth(), i[1]
                        + v.getHeight());
                view_to_rect.put(v, _rect);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
                    vto.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    vto.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This keeps the correct coordinates for the first fragment's buttons. But for the second fragment, the x-coordinate is relative to the first fragment. So I get the button's x coordinate within this fragment **PLUS** the first fragment width. The y-coordinate is, of course, correct within all fragment.

Comment: Please show us some code

Comment: Please see my edition above :)

Comment: Problem solved - I used getX()...Thanks anyway